# Automate iOS tests using selenium webdriver on actual device

Tags: ios, ruby, selenium

I downloaded iwebDriver project and installed it in ipad. The server starts on "http://10.10.10.55:3001/wd/hub". And I want to hit "www.google.com" on it, but I get errors. I am pasting code below and the stacktrace as well.

Note : It works perfectly on iOS simulator but fails on ipad. My iPad version 4.3.3, XCode version is 4.2 and iOS SDK is 5.1

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://10.10.10.55:3001/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => "ipad"
browser.get "http://www.google.com"
```

and i am getting error:-

> URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: (null):(null) (or bad hostname?)
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:199:in `initialize'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/http.rb:78:in`initialize'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:177:in `new'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:177:in`parse'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:628:in `parse'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:57:in`request'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in`raw_execute'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:92:in `create_session'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in`initialize'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `new'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in`for'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:65:in `for'
>       from (irb):5
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in`'

And when I used "https" , I see the following-

```
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "https://10.10.10.55:3001/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => "ipad"
```

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in`block in connect'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in`timeout'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in`do_start'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in`request'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:76:in `response_for'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in`request'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in`raw_execute'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:92:in `create_session'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in`initialize'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `new'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in`for'
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@playerTests/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.22.2/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:65:in `for'
>       from (irb):6
>       from /Users/rohit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in`'1.9.2p290 :007 >

Please suggest, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: The ip that you have in code http://10.10.10.55:3001 is your ipad ip address? Are you able to see IWebDriverReady message when you access http://10.10.10.55:3001/wd/hub outside ipad?

Comment: Hey, Thanks A.J for looking at it. Yes 10.10.10.55:300/wd/hub is accessible for me outside ipad. 10.10.10.55:3001 is my ipad IP address. I can see there "iWebDriver Ready" message. Works perfectly on iphone actual device also , but not ipad.

Comment: Hmm..When you installed the iWebDriver in ipad, did you make sure to change the configuration in XCode to "ipad" from "iphone"?

Comment: Yes, I made changes in configuration of Xcode to "ipad" from "iphone". Is the selenium webdriver works for ipad actual device?

Comment: Yes. It works fine for me.I connect it to a grid and run the tests in grid mode. Only problem is ipad drops wifi connection after a while. Thats a known issue with ipad

Comment: Thanks, A.J can you please tell me how to run tests in Grid mode in ipad?

Comment: Sure. Its easy. After installing the webdriver app, go to settings-> Iwebdriver. You will see a host and port name in there. Give the hostname and port of the hub and restart the app. Your ipad is now in grid..

Comment: A.J, I did changes you mentioned and my ipad is now in grid. Still I am getting same error. Don't know actually what happened.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and installing the app again? Make sure all your settings in xcode is correct.Which version of selenium server are you using?

Comment: Selenium - 2.22.2, xcode - 4.2, ios - 5.0 , ipad - 4.3.3, iphone - 5.0.1. yes I tried uninstalling and installing the app. Need to check xcode setting

Comment: Hey A.J, my xcode settings looks right. Still facing same problem. Can you please mention detail steps in 'Answer' part? so that I can follow those. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why selenium-webdriver was not working on ipad :-**

1. My ipad2 version is 4.3.3 and I installed iWebDriver project on same ipad2.
2. Tried to run simple ruby code, written in question.
3. Code was giving error, stack trace also pasted in question.

**How selenium-webdriver started working on ipad :-**

1. I installed iWebdriver project on 'New ipad' ios version 5.1. also it works on iphone 4S whose version is 5.0
2. And then ran simple ruby code

   ruby 'selenium-webdriver'
   driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, :url => "http://10.10.10.88:3001/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :ipad
3. desired_capabilities does not matter, you can give anything :iphone or :ipad
4. Above ruby code returned me the object and I can do:-

   driver.get "http://www.google.com"
5. And it worked.
6. I observed, there is iOS version dependency for selenium-webdriver to work on.

So, the questions are why selenium-webdriver does not work on iOS version below than 5.0 like 4.3.3, 4.3.1 etc.

Thanks everyone who helped me.